# What should i do to fix the NoSuchElementException error in my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get into a particular link(given in the code) and login using a user id and password. After logging in i want to click on a button named 'see all xxx reviews'. I am using selenium for this task. Unfortunately i am getting a error saying.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/.PyCharmEdu2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 16, in 
    username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('emailInput-input')

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"emailInput-input"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)**

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

`
usr = input('enter your user name : ')
psd = input('enter the password : ')

url = "https://www.coursera.org/courses?authMode=login&languages=en&query=big+data&userQuery=big+data"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('emailInput-input')
username_box.send_keys(usr)

pass_box = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordInput-input') #FHSU
pass_box.send_keys(psd)


login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="authentication-box-content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/button/span')
login_btn.submit()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ratings"]/div[2]/button').click()
```

Comment: may be that element was not loaded at that point of time,try doing explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another element identifier like `by_xpath` or `by_class_name`. It could be like @raviraja said and the element may not have loaded yet. You have `WebDriverWait` imported, just use something like `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, 'emailInput-input'))`.

Just make sure to import `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC` and `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`.